# jQuery validation on checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has 3 checkboxes and I need to do some custom jQuery validation.  Below is a copy of the 3 checkboxes.

What I would like to do is set it so that the user can only select one of the first 2 checkboxes (if they select the first one, make the 2nd one unavailable and vice versa. Then, if the user has selected one of the first 2 boxes, then they can select the 3rd checkbox.

Is anyone able to help with this?

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="upselldigitaldisplay" class="ap_upsellstandard ap_webupsellstandard ap_upsell_default_off ap_upsell_allowed_all" id="upselldigitaldisplay" value="1">

 <input type="checkbox" name="upsellenhancedclassificationad" class="ap_upsellstandard ap_webupsellstandard ap_upsell_default_off ap_upsell_allowed_all" id="upsellenhancedclassificationad" value="1">

 <input type="checkbox" name="upselljnpriority" class="ap_upsellstandard ap_webupsellstandard ap_upsell_default_off ap_upsell_allowed_all" id="upselljnpriority" value="1">
```

Comment: You can use a radio button for the first two checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I've whipped up on [JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wfjGm/](http://jsfiddle.net/wfjGm/)

As you don't have any ID's to work with I've had to go for element position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input:checkbox:eq(2)').attr("disabled", true);  // Step 1

    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){ // Step 2

            if ( ($('input:checkbox:eq(0)').is(':checked')) || ($('input:checkbox:eq(1)').is(':checked')) ){ // Step 3
                            $('input:checkbox:eq(2)').attr("disabled", false);   // Step 4          
            }


            else {    
                $('input:checkbox:eq(2)').attr("disabled", true); //Step 5
                }

    }); 

});
```

Step 1) Make 3rd checkbox disabled on document ready (:eq uses a 0 index, so the 3rd checkbox is element 2)

Step 2) Run a function on the click event every time a checkbox is clicked
Step 3) Check If the first or second checkboxes are checked or not and enable the 3rd checkbox if they are.
Step 4) Step 5 - a fall back statement to disable the checkbox if a user unselects one of the first two.



**QUICK EDIT**
If you want to ensure that the third checkbox is also unchecked when it's disabled if the first two are unchecked then change the else line in Step 5 to this...

```
$('input:checkbox:eq(2)').attr("disabled", true).attr("checked", false); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a solution for you where I [cache the selectors](http://mikeadamsnc.com/cache-jquery-selectors-for-better-performance/), and also use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for the demonstration's sake.

```
$(function() {
    var $options = $('.option');
    var $priority = $('#upselljnpriority');

    function uncheckOtherOptions(domElem) {
        if (domElem.checked) {
            $options.not(domElem).prop('checked', false);
        }
    }

    function togglePriorityAvailability() {
        if ($options.is(':checked')) {
            $priority.prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $priority.prop('disabled', true);
            $priority.prop('checked', false);
        }
    }

    $options.click(function () {
        uncheckOtherOptions(this);
        togglePriorityAvailability();
    });

    togglePriorityAvailability();
});
```

Note that I have added an `option` class to the first two options. This enables me to make very fast and clean selectors. Also this is a good practice, because your html code is extensible with more options without any JavaScript change. If this is not desired, you can use

```
var $options = $('#upselldigitaldisplay, #upsellenhancedclassificationad');
```

Notice that I have calculated `$options` and `$priority` outside the event handler at the beginning and never again! This way I cached my calculations for later use. This increases performance.

Notice that I have used [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for manipulating properties, as I have no intension of changing the attributes, just the properties.

Notice the line `$options.not(domElem).prop('checked', false);`. I have used [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with a DOM element as it's input. This means the original selector minus the given DOM element.

Notice that I have used named functions (`uncheckOtherOptions` and `togglePriorityAvailability`). I like them. They give a little more detail on what is going on and supposed to happen. Also by making `togglePriorityAvailability` a separate function I was able to reuse it (notice the last line which sets the last checkbox to it's correct state immediately on pageload).

I have also created a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pqWw8/)** for you to test this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest the following, though this requires some changes to your HTML (following the jQuery):

```
var radios = $('input[type="checkbox"].ap_upsellstandard');
radios.change(function () {
    var self = this,
        $self = $(self);
    if ($self.siblings().length) {
        // one of the first two:
        $self.siblings('input').prop('disabled', self.checked);
        $self.closest('fieldset').next('fieldset').toggle(self.checked);
    }
}).last().parent().hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r3wZE/).

The changed HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select <strong>one</strong> of the following:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="upselldigitaldisplay" class="ap_upsellstandard ap_webupsellstandard ap_upsell_default_off ap_upsell_allowed_all" id="upselldigitaldisplay" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="upsellenhancedclassificationad" class="ap_upsellstandard ap_webupsellstandard ap_upsell_default_off ap_upsell_allowed_all" id="upsellenhancedclassificationad" value="1" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="upselljnpriority" class="ap_upsellstandard ap_webupsellstandard ap_upsell_default_off ap_upsell_allowed_all" id="upselljnpriority" value="1" />
</fieldset>
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Is there a reason for `var self = this` here? Or is it just habit? Since there are no functions called on an other object here that can see this scope (like an event handler), I don't see a reason for it.

Comment: It's mainly habit, to be honest (though given the only use of the variable is the repeated `self.checked` it'd have made more sense to cache *that* instead).